# Conditional figure environment (sideways, bottom captions)

Tags: floats, captions, memoir, double-sided

For my phd dissertation I would like to have a new environment for figures that gives me the possibility to either place the caption `sideways` if there is enough space (say the figure width is < 0.6 column width) otherwise places the caption below the figure. The `sideways` caption should switch left and right based on `odd` `even` page too, and it can stretch the line width limit in that part. An example for the `sideways` captions: say the figure width is `0.5\columnwidth`, then the caption can start from `0.6\columnwidth` to `1.2\columnwidth`. Could someone give me the direction on how to realize this in `latex`?

For my thesis I am using `xelatex` - `memoir`. This is the type of `sideways` figures that I am looking for:

[image]

EDIT:
By the helpful comment of Ipsen and some tweaking I am managed to reach to the thing that I want although not perfect yet.

Code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}

\renewcommand*{\sidecapstyle}{%
\captionnamefont{\bfseries}%
\slshape%
}

\renewcommand*{\sidecapfloatwidth}{0.5\linewidth}
\setsidecaps{0.1\textwidth}{.55\textwidth}
\sidecapmargin{outer}
\setsidecappos{b}
\strictpagecheck
\sidecapraise 0.05\textheight

\begin{document}

\chapter{Captions}
\begin{figure}[tb]
\raggedright
\begin{sidecaption}{This is a subcaption just for illustration purposes. This is a subcaption just for illustration purposes. 
This is a subcaption just for illustration purposes. Page number is \LARGE\textbf{\thepage}}[fig:test]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Picture}
\end{sidecaption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-2]

\begin{figure}[tb]
\raggedleft
\begin{sidecaption}{This is a subcaption just for illustration purposes. This is a subcaption just for illustration purposes. 
This is a subcaption just for illustration purposes - Page number is \LARGE\textbf{\thepage}}[fig:test]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Picture}
\end{sidecaption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Page 1 of output:
[image]

Page 2 of output:
[image]

As you see `page` number in `float` is not correct, thus, I have problem automatically parsing `\raggedleft` and `\raggedright` after `\begin{figure}`. How does `sidecaption` find which page it is now?

Comment: switching bottom or to the right is fairly easy, but switching sides would require fairly extensive changes (probably simplest to do a multiple pass version where you extract from the aux file reference the page number) The problem is that latex sets floats into a box before it knows which page they will land on.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, It seems that the answer on the bottom switches sides correctly.

Comment: yes i should have noticed you are using memoir, which does of course do lots of things:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand your question you want the margin note to be ragged towards the margin it is typeset in. This answer is based on Lars Madsen's answer to [memoir: sidecaption: ragged against the text block not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66198/memoir-sidecaption-ragged-against-the-text-block-not-working).

For you particular example `\strictpagecheck` is still needed because the float is moved to the next page. A full working example based on you work is encluded here. Please note that this is very depedent on memoir.

**EDIT:** The code now provides the `raggedsidecap` and `raggedsidecap2` environments. The optional argument is the label for the caption. The first argument is the width of the float and the second is the caption text. The inside of the environment is placed in the float.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}


% This you can set any way you want
\renewcommand*{\sidecapstyle}{%
  \captionnamefont{\bfseries}%
  \slshape%
}

\sidecapmargin{outer} % Place in the outer margin
\setsidecappos{c} % Align the caption at the center of the float
\sidecapraise 0.02\textheight  % Raise the caption a little - aestetic

% ----------------- % 
% Raggedsidecaption %
% ----------------- %

\strictpagecheck  % This is necessary because of overflow to next page
\newlength{\scapindentlength}          % Length so that float is aligned right on even sides
\newlength{\maxsidecapfloatwidth}      
\newlength{\sidecapintomargin}     % The distance the sidecaption will stick into the margin

\setlength{\sidecapsep}{0.1\linewidth} % Distance between float and caption 
\setlength{\scapindentlength}{\marginparwidth+\sidecapsep+\marginparsep} % Do not touch !
\setlength{\maxsidecapfloatwidth}{0.6\linewidth}
\setlength{\sidecapintomargin}{0.25\linewidth}

% Calculate how wide the sidecation can be if it should only stick \sidecapintomargin into
% margin, have a separtion of between float and caption of \sidecapsep and the float is
% \maxsidefloatwidth.
\setlength{\sidecapwidth}{\linewidth+\sidecapintomargin-\maxsidecapfloatwidth-\sidecapsep}

% Arguments:
% 1: (Optional) the label for the caption
% 2: The width of the float
% 3: Caption text
% Between begin and end: Everything there is placed in the float.
\newenvironment{raggedsidecap}[3][]
{
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand*{\sidecapfloatwidth}{#2}
  \setlength{\sidecapwidth}{\linewidth-#2-\sidecapsep+\sidecapintomargin}
  \addtolength{\scapindentlength}{\maxsidecapfloatwidth-#2-\sidecapsep}

 \begin{sidecaption}{#3}[#1]
}
{
  \end{sidecaption}
  \endgroup
}

\newenvironment{raggedsidecap2}[3][]
{
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand*{\sidecapfloatwidth}{#2}
  \addtolength{\scapindentlength}{\maxsidecapfloatwidth-#2-\sidecapsep}
  \addtolength{\sidecapsep}{\maxsidecapfloatwidth-#2}
  \begin{sidecaption}{#3}[#1]
}
{
  \end{sidecaption}
  \endgroup
}


% Here be dragons. Overwrite of memoir methods. Do not touch  
\makeatletter  
\def\endsidecaption{%
  \m@mscapend@fbox
  \refstepcounter\@captype
  \m@mscaplabel
  \m@mscapcheckside %<---- added this
  \begin{lrbox}{\m@mscap@capbox}%
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\sidecapwidth}%
      \sidecapstyle
      \@caption\@captype[\m@mscap@fortoc]{\m@mscap@forcap}
    \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \m@mscapopboxes}
\renewcommand*{\m@mscapopboxes}{%
  % Correctly indented from margin
  \ifscapmargleft%
    \hspace{\scapindentlength}%
  \else\fi%
  %
  \m@mcalcscapraise
  \usebox{\m@mscap@fbox}%\m@mscapcheckside %<--- removed here
  \ifscapmargleft%
  \rlap{\kern-\m@mscaplkern
    \raisebox{\m@mscapraise}{\usebox{\m@mscap@capbox}}}%
  \else%
  \rlap{\kern\sidecapsep
    \raisebox{\m@mscapraise}{\usebox{\m@mscap@capbox}}}%
  \fi
  \gdef\m@mscapthisside{}%
  \@mem@scap@afterhook%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% \chapter{Captions}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{raggedsidecap}[ref:ref]{0.4\linewidth}
    { This is a subcaption just for illustration purposes. This is a subcaption just for
      illustration purposes.  This is a subcaption just for illustration purposes. Page number
      is \LARGE\textbf{\thepage}
    }
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Picture}
  \end{raggedsidecap}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
  \begin{raggedsidecap2}{0.4\linewidth}
    { This is a subcaption just for illustration purposes. This is a subcaption just for
      illustration purposes.  This is a subcaption just for illustration purposes. Page number
      is \LARGE\textbf{\thepage}
    }
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Picture}
  \end{raggedsidecap2}
\end{figure}



\lipsum[2-6]
\begin{figure}
  \begin{raggedsidecap}{0.4\linewidth}
    { This is a subcaption just for illustration purposes. This is a subcaption just for
      illustration purposes.  This is a subcaption just for illustration purposes. Page number
      is \LARGE\textbf{\thepage} }
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Picture}
  \end{raggedsidecap}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{raggedsidecap2}{0.4\linewidth}
    { This is a subcaption just for illustration purposes. This is a subcaption just for
      illustration purposes.  This is a subcaption just for illustration purposes. Page number
      is \LARGE\textbf{\thepage} }
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Picture}
  \end{raggedsidecap2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Munken. I don't have any problem with the caption itself since I want it justified as it is in the post. What I need is removing the `\raggedleft` and `\raggedright` after `\begin{figure}`.

Comment: @rowman Have updated the code, so the text will not flow out of the page.

The problem here is that we need to measure the width of the image. This can be accomplished by making this a macro like    
\sidecap[label]{caption}{onpage}
Where the onpage would be the \includegraphics statement.

Do I understand you correctly that if the image is wider than 0.5\linewidth then you want ordinary captions ?

Comment: Thanks Munken for the followup. About your question, yes it is correct. Although I will choose myself either to go with sideway or ordinary bottom captions. No need for code to do this. more practical and easier. `0.5\linewidth` was just an example. I want the picture on the second page `raggedleft` to save space just as the picture on the first page should always be `raggedright`. Now the second one is not aligned to the left, nor the first one if you change the image size.

Comment: @rowman Your last comment is a little hard to understand, but I made the code issue the fitting ragging command based of what king of sidecaption it is. It might require you to recompile sometimes. If you can break the code please post how.

Comment: If you modify the image width in `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]` to say '0.8\linewidth', the image is not `\raggedright` any more (does not align to the left). In your code the horizontal position of caption is always the same and float is placed according to that. However, the float position should always be fixed and caption should be placed according to it. Thanks

Comment: @rowman Updated the code so that it now aligns when the picture is \linewidth. Not sure how to do it if the picture is not filling up it's entire space, except wrapping it in a macro.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort and the code is almost perfect. Just as the last comment: I can always include the picture `\linewidth` wide, and locally change `\sidecapfloatwidth`. However, this method only works for the first picture and the second picture is again not aligned. If this can be solved it would be great, because now I am forced to include pictures `0.5\linewidth` wide.

Comment: @rowman Here we go again. I introduced the conditionalsidecap environment. The options are [caption]{float-width}{text}. As of now the maximum with are 0.6\linewith which is what I can squeeze in with deafault margins. 

There are to versions of the environment. One that adjusts the separation between the float and the caption and one that adjusts the width. The caption is always placed \raggedleft or right.

The current code demonstrates both methods.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Can be used right away now. It would be really great if you could put some comments on your TeX codes, to be more explanatory. Thanks !

Comment: @rowman There you go. Made lengths, instead of the different magic numbers, with comments to explain them. This should made the code more customizable. The environment is renamed to raggedsidecap.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you chould use `sidecaption`. I would think that you need two figure enviroments: one ordinary and one for "sideway"-captions. The main idea would be to do something like

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setsidecaps{5mm}{.7\textwidth}
\sidecapmargin{outer}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Captions}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{adjustwidth*}{0pt}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{sidecaption}{This figure shows that you should not make figures like this.}
\centering
{\huge FIGURE}
\end{sidecaption}
\end{adjustwidth*}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
{\huge FIGURE}
\caption{This is a figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{adjustwidth*}{0pt}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{sidecaption}{This figure shows that you should not make figures like this.}
\centering
{\huge FIGURE}
\end{sidecaption}
\end{adjustwidth*}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

You can change the margin width etc. to fit with your layout. To do so, take a look at section 10.10 in [memman](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf). To define a new float enviroment take a look at the `\newfloat` command in memman section 10.1. I don't know if it is possible to change the width automatically; if not you have to include this an additional argument. I hope this helps a little :)

Comment: Good thing is that switching the caption sideway to the left or right works. That one is the most challenging.